# Setting spinner position dynamically in android?

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

I am developing an app where i need to set spinner values dynamically based on previous screen values. My code...

Main.java.

```
String[] values = {"All","Only Walk-in","Only Phone","Only Web","Walkin-phone","Walkin-web","phone-web"};

 /*ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,apttypes);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);*/
```

But here what i want is from previous screen i am getting some value (like spinner postion). based on that i need to set spinner value to display...

Means from previous screen if i got values =0 means,

i need to set spinner value to display "All" from values array at top.

If i got value= 5 means,

i want to set spinner value to display as "Walkin-web"

How can i do that. can anyone help me with this...

Comment: Did you try in anyother methods? Share yours source code..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pass the value in from the previous `Activity` using extras in the `Intent` you use to launch it. Then when you've read the value call

```
int position = getIntent().getIntExtra( "name", defaultValue );
spinner.setSelection( position );
```

Which will move the spinner to the index you selected.

Comment: can i set the spinner value by its value not by setting the position??

Comment: Not directly but you can always read through your values to find the index of the one you want and set that.

Answer (score 3):

Use following array code and create new array adapter each time

```
 String[] str=new String[maxsize-4];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
you can implement onItemClick event on Spinner like this and setSelection(position)

        //Spinner OnItemClick Event here
        payfeeTabStudentNameSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                payfeeTabStudentNameSpinner.setSelection(position);
                spinnerSelectedValue = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your First Activity A.java

```
public static String Position = YOUR_SPINNER1.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

Inside your Second Activity B.java

```
    if(A.Position.equals("0")){
//Set your adapter accordingly
 }else if(A.Position.equals("1")){
//Set your adapter accordingly
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the Spinner's Position using the following code..

```
 Spinner s1;
 -----------
 -----------
 int position=valueFromPrevious;
 s1.setSelection(position);
 -----------
 -----------
```

Comment: You can assign the Value of the Spinner from the Previous Class by the Above assignment Statement..

Comment: final String valueFromPrevious = getIntent().getExtras().getString("SpinnerPosition"); You can use this for the Value get from Previous..

Answer (score 0):

pass the values from previous activity using Extras and then when u want use it in your current activity follow this:

If u get String value then typecast it into interger by parseInt method...

```
String strtext4 = getIntent().getStringExtra("qualification");
```

then

```
int position = Integer.parseInt(strtext4);
```

after this just set it to your spinner

```
qualificationspinner.setSelection(position);
```